# GridView Design : How to add a Blank New Row in GridView after button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, data-binding

I have GridView with a Button beneath it. Upon clicking the button I want to Add a new blank row just beneath the GridView

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:Button ID="btnTest" Text="Test" runat="server" OnClick="btnTest_Click" />
        </div>

        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <strong>Dynamic Grid</strong></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:GridView ID="GrdDynamic" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true"
                         OnRowDataBound="GrdDynamic_RowDataBound" >
                    </asp:GridView>
  </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and the data is being populated by below way....

In pageLoad I am calling the bind

```
 DataTable dt = GroupBudgetSetUpBLL.Instance.GetAllGroupBudgetSetUp();
            GrdDynamic.DataSource = dt;
            GrdDynamic.DataBind();
```

and in rowdatabound I am making the Grid Editable textbox.

```
protected void GrdDynamic_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)
        {
            TextBox txt = new TextBox();
            string budget = e.Row.Cells[i].Text.Split('_').LastOrDefault();
            string txtID = e.Row.Cells[i].Text.Split('_').FirstOrDefault() + "_" + e.Row.Cells[i].Text.Split('_').Skip(1).FirstOrDefault();
            txt.ID = txtID;
            txt.Text = budget;
            e.Row.Cells[i].Text = "";
            e.Row.Cells[i].Controls.Add(txt);
        }
    }
}
```

Now upon clicking the "Button" below the Grid I want to display a blank row just beneath the MainGrid , cells control type will be TextBox so that it remains editable.

Answer (score 0):

What I could infer from your question is that you need to add a new blank row beneath the GridView (looking like the last row of the GridView is blank on button_click).

I am not sure how feasible it is to add a new Row to the databound Grid View but instead what you could do is to add a blank row in the data table like below:

Add the below code to your `button1_Click()`:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable dt = GroupBudgetSetUpBLL.Instance.GetAllGroupBudgetSetUp();
            DataRow myRow = dt.NewRow();
            dt.Rows.InsertAt(myRow, dt.Rows.Count);
            GrdDynamic.DataSource = dt;
            GrdDynamic.DataBind();
        }
```